# Saving private variables on a spring @Service

Tags: java, spring

I want to save data on a spring `@Service` to be used every time the service is called.

Is it a good idea to save it as a private class member like in the example below?

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private int counter;

    @Override
    public int increment() {
        return counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be problematic, because spring beans are singleton by Default. It depends on theuse of it

Comment: If you want to do that, use at least one of the atomic datatypes (like AtomicInteger or AtomicLong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem with that. You need to deal with concurrency anyway, no matter how you are going to abstract it:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private static AtomicInteger COUNTER = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public int increment() {
        return COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to wrap the AtomicInteger into your class.

Comment: @PetarPetrov Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is bad idea because it's not thread safe and maybe you break the Single Responsibility principle.

If i understand right you want to generate new number every time when you call the method. I suggest you to create class `@Component` `NumberGenerator` which will generate numbers and you can inject it your service. Then you can call it in your service.

If you create an interface of `NumberGenerator` + DI you can easily change implementations instead of hard coding your logic in your service.

I hope this will help you to decide which way is better.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the counter is being used for. If it is just a rough idea of how many times the something is called, I'd make it `private` and call it inside. If it is called 934957453 times, nobody really cares if it is out by 1%/2% so I wouldn't bother with synchronising it.

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private int counter=0;

    private int increment() {
        return counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public getNumberOfCalls() {
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    public int someMethod() {
        increment();
        ...
    }
}
```

However, if the counter is used in some way to do auditing, request tracking, creating unique ids or not just a counter then you would have to synchronise it and make sure you can not get duplicates.

Comment: If it is not called often, synchronizing is not a threat to performance. If it is called often, chances are good you run into concurrency issues. So not synchronizing it is inferior anyway.

Comment: I disagree, synchronizing _is_ a threat to performance. In a highly concurrent system threads will block against each other as they try to increment the counter. You may think that getting the number perfectly correct all the time is important but in a lot of cases it actually isn't and some margin for error is acceptible in order to remove a synchonized block. Like I said, there isn't enough information in the OP's question to give a proper answer as we don't know how the counter is being used and the importance it has.